# Files are not Updating online

Tags: wordpress, ftp

I am working on wordpress, I dont have access to cpanel but FTP. whenever I upload Images, and delete them, they are not deleting completely. for example, If I upload an image abc.png, then delete it from media(in WP).It will give 404 error if i don't remove links of it. Now I made changes to the file and reupload it.. it shows the previous result.

secondly, I am working on PHP template file, it is going good, but a Javascript file is not updating. however, I could see file content from FTP and it is changed. but on WP, It shows old one. What is the problem, with what?

Comment: WordPress creates various different versions (sizes) of each image uploaded.  It's possible what you're seeing is not the newly uploaded image, but an old (differently-sized) WordPress generated image.  Try regenerating the thumbnails with the Regenerate Thumbnails plugin (https://en-au.wordpress.org/plugins/regenerate-thumbnails/)

Answer (score 0):

**For Media Library Issue**
This plugin is specifically for letting you sync changes that have been made throuh ftp:

https://wordpress.org/plugins/ftp-sync/

**For Javascript Issue :**

- I think this may occur due to cache issue.If you have cache plugin the do clear cache.Or please use a Private Browser.
- You can use a version for js issue.Attach a version number to Js while enqueue.

**Folder Permission**

```
chown www-data:www-data -R *
find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;  //for folder
find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \; // for file
```

Where ftp-user is what user you are using to upload the files

```
chown -R ftp-user:www-data wp-content
chmod -R 775 wp-content
```

Comment: What I think issue is folder permission, I cannot install plugins from WP Plugin options, I have to upload from FTP. 

I cleared cache, deleted history, even changed browser, result is same.

Comment: check permission of folder

Comment: its 775 , I cannot change it to 777 because I am only working as web developer, website owner forbid me to change permissions on my own. I heard that If i change it to 777 then hackers can bypass security and can cause damage to website and content.

Comment: yes you are write never use 777 it means you give access to external entity.